# How can i open the __init__.py file to edit it?

Tags: python, tor

I have been advised elsewhen on this forum that to correct an issue (with connection to Tor-Browser) I can "fix this by going into the **init**.py file and changing the lines (98) in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/: "

HOWEVER, I am 74 years old and not tech-savy. Is there a kind soul who can let me know how I can open the **init**.py file and edit it?

Many thanks
Duncan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

1. open a terminal
2. go the path where the ****init**.py** file is stored.
3. Use the Nano Editor to open the file: `nano __init__.py`
4. Make edits as necessary. Be carefull not to change anything else.
5. Store the edited file pressing CTRL+o
6. Press CTRL+X to leave Nano

Done. Depending on the rights of the file and where it is stored you need to run Nano with root-permission, so `sudo nano __init__.py`.

Comment: Perhaps when you have path'd you should backup the file before editing it with nano or gedit. Before you edit, type `sudo cp filename.py filename.py.original` or some such.

Comment: Thank you very much - very kind of you - MUCH appreciated.